# How do I loop through a json_decode with foreach?`

Tags: php, json

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [href] => http://www.google.com
            [description] => search
            [extended] => 
            [meta] => x
            [hash] => x
            [time] => 2013-04-09T02:00:57Z
            [shared] => yes
            [toread] => no
            [tags] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [href] => http://shop.frankchimero.com/collections/frontpage/products/the-shape-of-design-digital-preorder
            [description] => 
            [extended] => 
            [meta] => x
            [hash] => x
            [time] => 2013-04-06T19:39:51Z
            [shared] => yes
            [toread] => no
            [tags] => 
        )
```

I have an array like that, but I don't know how to parse through it. How do I do, "foreach 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. get href"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) with option TRUE to return your result set as an array, then loop through the array.

```
$data = json_decode($my_array, TRUE);

foreach($data as $info) {
  echo $info['href'];
  echo $info['time'];
  //etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
foreach($yourJSONArrayName as $jsonObject)
{
  echo $jsonObject->href;   //etc
//print_r($jsonObject);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($jsonPages as $page)
{
    var_dump($page->href);
}
```